# making phone call from DialogBox in Android

Tags: android

I have one DialogBox with 2 buttons. If we click the +ve button, it attempts to open the Dialing Pad; else if we click the -ve button it closes the dialog. When I click the +ve button it shows the null exception. If the same code executes without the DialogBox, it is fine.

Here is my code:

```
callDialog.setPositiveButton("Call Now", new android.DialogInterface.
                OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent dial = new Intent();
                dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
                try {
                    dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9951037343"));
                    startActivity(dial);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Calling", "" + e.getMessage());
                }


            }

        }
```

I've given permissions in the manifest file as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

Comment: HI,is there any differences making a process from normally calling and calling from DialogBox

Comment: Also you can create intent with action like this:
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:phonenumber");
startActivity(call);
```

Comment: ,at present my device is not detecting,but I'l try

Answer (score 1):

Remove the @Overrride line.
Like this:

```
callDialog.setPositiveButton("Call Now", new android.DialogInterface.
            OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent dial = new Intent();
            dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
            try {
                dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9951037343"));
                startActivity(dial);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Calling", "" + e.getMessage());
            }


        }

    }
```

----UPDATE-----

Since you havent posted any logcat, its hard to know where it crashes. Try this block:

```
AlertDialog.Builder callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    callDialog.setTitle("My title");
    callDialog.setMessage("My message");
    callDialog.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            Intent dial = new Intent();
            dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
            try {
                dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9951037343"));
                startActivity(dial);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Calling", "" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    callDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    callDialog.show();
```

Comment: hi @Sebastina,it is not working,can u give me any better solutions

Comment: Log.e("CALLING...", ""+e.getMessage()); is null

Comment: Is it a right syntax : callDialog.setPositiveButton("Call Now", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

Comment: @knvchowdary put this instead getApplicationContext().startActivity(dial);

Answer (score 0):

```
    use this code......

    String number = "tel:" + phonenumber;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                            .parse(number));
                    startActivity(intent);

    give permission in manifest:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


updated.....



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.menu_icon_pager).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)

                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)

                .setTitle("Exit")

                .setMessage(
                        "Texting from dialog")

                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)

                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                // Exit the activity


                                String number = "tel:"+phonenumber ;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                                        .parse(number));
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                        })

                .show();




            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: hi,can U try this functionality from DialogBox ?

Comment: Because,I did this without DialogBox so.

Comment: at startActivity(intent);

Comment: Is it a right code : callDialog.setPositiveButton("Call Now", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

Comment: I think you have some wrong imports..... due to whick u r getting null pointer exception ...

Comment: Hi,my imports are import android.app.AlertDialog;
      import android.content.DialogInterface;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following---

```
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
//dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
                try {
                    dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9951037343"));
                    startActivity(dial);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Calling", "" + e.getMessage());
                }
startActivity(dial);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanx for giving the answers,now I'm trying to get result.

Comment: @knvchowdary, you welcome. Since you are new to this site let me guide you, how you should accept the answer. Just tick the tick mark beside the answer which is best solution for your problem. :)

Comment: @Ved Prakash,still I'm not able to attempt the call,can U guess where I made a mistake

Comment: @knvchowdary - No, the following code has no mistake. Just try the above code on a simple button click and see if it works. Example - `findViewById(R.id.callDialog).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//Your code here..}`

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);`

instead of this

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL"); // but this line is an optional one
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:044 6000 6000"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: ,I think "Intent.ACTION_CALL" is for attempting the call,I want open the Dialing Pad,and in last time I tried for calling also,but I didnt get from either.

Comment: ,I tried to call from DialogBox,but the same code worked from Activity,but not from DialogBox.Is there any other way to call from DialogBox.

Comment: Is it right code :- callDialog.setPositiveButton("Call Now", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I called the AlertDialog from another Activity,so I need the context of called 
>   Activity's Context reference.So I passed the Context as a parameter to Called Activity
>   Here is Called Activity's code

if(position == 1)new CalledByActivity().dailingDialogBox(param1,
    param2,context);//Here I'm passing the context as param

> Here CalledBy activity's implemented function

```
public void dailingDialogBox(final String param1,String param2,final Context context){
```

> Here I implemented in +ve button click

```
Intent dail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
dail.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+station_Number));
context.startActivity(dail);//Here the "context" is reference of called Activity's context
```

Comment: HI every one,Thanks for ur participation,here I discover the solution by the help of my colleague,"startActivity()" should be the help of Context object of called Activity,then only it can start the Activity,else null pointer exception is raising.Thanks again & again.

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why it is an answer.

Comment: Hi all,I hope that U may understand.